# Custom Blog using input Files

Tags: blog

I would like to create a blog page on my WP site using the following mechanism:
1 Users write their text to a local .txt file
2 txt Files are uploaded daily onto the WP site using FTP
3 The WP blog site, when loaded, should read those files and create blog entries programmatically.

I do not know how to approach the last part (3). Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks!